Gross asymmetry in Maxwell Equations
Consider the statement of the vacuum Maxwell equations in the language of differential forms. The equation of motion in terms of the field strength $2$-form $F$ is
$$d \star F = 0,$$
which follows from applying the principle of stationary action to the electromagnetism action. This yields two of the four Maxwell equations. The remaining two Maxwell equations are obtained from the mathematical fact that exact forms are closed
$$F = dA \implies dF = 0.$$
Is this asymmetry in the origin of these two pairs of Maxwell equations just an artifact of how we formalize electromagnetism in the language of differential forms? Or, are the Maxwell equations obtained from the action principle genuinely distinguished from the other two equations?

The fact that these two Maxwell equations are equivalent to the usual four tells us that we really should interpret $dF=0$ as a triviality. More generally, this is a (differential) Bianchi identity for the curvature 2-form of electrodynamics, and Bianchi identities are of course true and purely geometric statements. So then the question becomes “why describe electrodynamics using the curvature of a connection”, and ultimately the reason of course boils down to agreement with experiment.

@peek-a-boo experiment does not require describing Maxwell equations in terms of potential $A^\mu$, using $\mathbf E,\mathbf B$ is fine. In A-based formulation, $dF = 0$ can be either assumed, or derived from the action principle, see my answer.

@JánLalinský I didn’t say experiment requires Maxwell’s equations be described using potentials. I mean that Maxwell’s equations written as $dF=0, d(*F)=J$, or at the level of curvatures on vector bundles associated to the $U(1)$ principal bundle, $d_{\nabla}F=0$ (Bianchi’s identity) and $d_{\nabla}(*F)=J$ (source equations) clearly are formulated using a connection. And I’m simply saying that the reason why we should even consider believing any of this mathematical stuff is because it recovers the usual 4 Maxwell’s equations in vector calculus form, and that agrees with classical experiments.

@peek-a-boo thank you for clearing that up. The statement about triviality is confusing to me. If experiment is the reason for believing this mathematical stuff, then $dF=0$ is a compression of knowledge obtained from experiments, thus not trivial. It is only trivial if we already assume existence of $A$, and that $F$ is given by $dA$.

@JánLalinský the trivial part is the mathematics: $d^2=0$ (or that $d_{\nabla}F=0$, which is Bianchi’s identity). The non-trivial part is the bridge between the math and the physics. On the one hand we have these math facts, and on the other hand we have electromagnetic phenomena which we have to model somehow. I’m now saying that if we now decide to model the field strength as as a closed 2-form, this is consistent with what we observe empirically in the guise of Gauss’ law and Faraday’s law. And one level higher: our choice to model E&M using curvature of a connection encapsulates these two.

in other words, if in our lab we found that Faraday’s law (and hence electric generators) doesn’t work the way it currently does, then it would be inappropriate to describe E&M using a closed 2-form $F$ (or one level up: it would be inappropriate/inconsistent to describe the field strength as the curvature of a a certain connection), and in this case we need some different equations. So I’m saying experiment is the reason why we use this mathematical formalism (otherwise, we’d need to describe the field strength using some other type of object, not the curvature of a connection).

@peek-a-boo ok I think we agree, $dF=0$ is a triviality in theories where $F=dA$, but the fact these theories are consistent with the world is not a triviality, but experimentally obtained knowledge.

At the level of the vacuum equations, you can certainly find some form $C$ such that $\star F = dC$ (up to the usual statements about the topology of the underlying space.)  You would then have $d(\star F) = 0$ automatically,  and you could formulate the entirety of vacuum electrodynamics in terms of $C$, instead of its usual formulation in terms a one-form $A$ where $dA = F$.
It's only in the presence of sources that the two sets of equations are distinguished;  we have $d F = 0$ always but $d(\star F) = J$, where $J$ is the current density 3-form.  Since electric charge exists in profusion but magnetic charge seems not to exist at all,1 that means that we're stuck with formulating things in terms of $A$ in an asymmetric sort of way.

1 Except possibly for that one time at Stanford in 1982.

The apparent asymmetry is due to how we usually today formulate the action principle: focusing on the Euler-Lagrange equations for $A^\nu$, which give the source Maxwell equations, and forgetting about (taking for granted) the interpretation of the anti-symmetric derivative $\partial^\mu A^\nu - \partial^\nu A^\mu$ in terms of electric and magnetic field $\mathbf E, \mathbf B$ (the relation $F^{\mu\nu} = \partial^\mu A^\nu - \partial^\nu A^\mu$). But there are several different formulations, taking different assumptions and deriving different results. And if we want, we can derive all Maxwell's equations and also the above relation between $A$ and $F$ from a single action principle.
The standard way is that we assume 1) there exists a basic field $A^\nu$ that plays the role of a Lagrangian coordinate, and we assume 2) the usual Lagrangian functional of the field variables $A^\nu, \partial^\mu A^\nu$ in a prescribed current density $J^\nu$. From these assumptions we can derive the Euler-Lagrange equations referring to sources $\partial_\mu (\partial^\mu A^\nu - \partial^\nu A^\mu) = \mu_0 J^\nu$.
Then to interpret these equations in terms of electric and magnetic fields $\mathbf E,\mathbf B$, and check if we get Maxwell's equations for $\mathbf E,\mathbf B$, we additionally assume 3) that electric and magnetic field are given by the anti-symmetric derivatives $\partial^\mu A^\nu - \partial^\nu A^\mu$ (and not something else). This third assumption already also implies the equations $\nabla \cdot 
 \mathbf B = 0, \nabla \times \mathbf E = - \partial_t \mathbf B$ denoted by $dF=0$, irrespective of any particular choice of the Lagrangian.
However, there are different "principles of stationary action", in that they represent different schemes of assumptions and implications.
Historically, the first one proposed by Larmor [1], works in 3D space and assumes the source Maxwell equations (those we usually get from a particular Lagrangian in the above procedure); and it derives the source-free equations ($dF=0$) from the Lagrangian $\int_V \frac{1}{8\pi}(\mathbf H^2-\mathbf E^2) dV$ (in CGS). So in this old deprecated way of doing things, the asymmetry is reversed; we assumed $\star d\star F = J$, and derived $dF=0$.
But this possibility to derive $dF=0$ from the action principle is not limited to that old way which assumes the source Maxwell's equations. It is actually possible to derive all Maxwell's equations, and the assumption 3), from the appropriate action principle. That is, to derive that electric and magnetic field are given by the antisymmetric derivatives of $A$, and also to derive all the Maxwell equations. This can be achieved if we adopt a consistent Lagrangian that includes not only variables of the field, but also variables of the matter, and get from it the equations of motion for those matter variables. From those equations, we can then justify why it is the antisymmetric derivative of $A$, and not some other function of $A^\nu,\partial^\mu A^\nu$, which gives values of the observable electric and magnetic field.
For example of such a Lagrangian, we can consider a set of $N$ point charged particles, described by the Frenkelian Lagrangian (see [2],[3]) where particle $a$ has charge $q_a$, position $\mathbf r_a$, velocity $\mathbf v_a$ and four-velocity $u_a^\mu$, and we also use the notation $j_a^\mu = \frac{1}{\gamma_a}q_a u_a^\mu \delta(\mathbf x- \mathbf r_a)$:
$$
L = \int_V -\frac{1}{2\mu_0}\sum_a \sum_b{}^{'}F_a^{\mu\nu}F_{b,\mu\nu} + \sum_a \sum_b{}^{'} j_{a,\mu}A_b^{\mu}~ dV -\sum_a m_ac^2\sqrt{1-v_a^2/c^2}.
$$
For this Lagrangian it can be shown from the Euler-Lagrange equations (exercise left to the reader) that velocities of the charged particles obey the equations of motion
$$
\frac{dp_a^\mu}{dt} = \frac{1}{\gamma_a}(\partial^\mu A_{-a}^\nu - \partial^\nu A_{-a}^\mu ) q_a u_{a,\nu},\tag{*}
$$
where the anti-symmetric derivative of $A$ appears. Notation:  $p_a$ is the particle momentum $p_a^\mu = m_a u_a^\mu$, $A_{-a}$ is a shorthand for $\sum_b{}^{'}A_b(\mathbf r_a,t)$ (summation excluding the case $b=a$, as there is no self-interaction in Frenkelian theories).
We can see here the time component(power) and spatial components(force) are the same functions of the four-velocity components, as we know from the four-dimensional expression of the Lorentz force and power in terms of electric and magnetic fields:
$$
F_{-a}^{\mu\nu} q_a \frac{1}{\gamma_a} u_{a,\nu} = [q_a\mathbf E_{-a}\cdot \mathbf v_a,q_a\mathbf E_{-a} + q_a\mathbf v_a\times\mathbf B_{-a}],
$$
where the index $-a$ means the field is the effective field acting on the particle $a$; $F_{-a}^{\mu\nu}$ is the well-known anti-symmetric matrix of electric and magnetic field components, known from the special-relativistic formulation of the Lorentz force and power on single charged particle.
Let us assume the above Lorentz functions of fields $\mathbf E,\mathbf B$ and velocity $\mathbf v$ give correctly the EM power and force on a single particle. This is an operational definition of the effective electric and magnetic field $\mathbf E,\mathbf B$ acting on the particle. Comparing these expressions to the result of the action principle (*), we are lead to the conclusion that the matrix $F$ of effective field components acting on the particle $a$ can be expressed in terms of variables $A^\nu$ this way:
$$
F_{-a}^{\mu\nu} = \partial^\mu A_{-a}^\nu - \partial^\nu A_{-a}^\mu,\tag{**}
$$
so we have
$$
\text{electric field}~E^k = F^{0k}c = c(\partial^0 A^k - \partial^k A^0),
$$
and
$$
\text{magnetic field}~B^{ik} = F^{ik} = \partial^i A^k - \partial^k A^i.
$$
Thus we have derived from 1) the action principle with the given Lagrangian and from 2) the operational definition of the effective EM field acting on a particle, that: the anti-symmetric derivative $\partial^\mu A_{-a}^\nu - \partial^\nu A_{-a}^\mu $ gives the tensor of effective electric and magnetic field acting on the particle $a$.
From this, it also follows $\partial^\rho F^{\mu\nu} + \partial^\mu F^{\nu\rho} + \partial^\nu F^{\rho\mu}  = 0$, or $dF=0$ for each $F_{-a}$ ($N$ distinct effective fields), and thus the same holds also for each individual particle adjunct field $F_b$, or any partial or full sum of them.
The other (source) Maxwell equations can be derived from the Euler-Lagrange equations for the field variables $A_b^\mu,\partial^\nu A_b^\mu$.
[1] J. Larmor, Aether and matter,  Cambridge University Press, (1900), p.82-86
[2] J. Frenkel, Zur Elektrodynamik punktfoermiger Elektronen, Zeits. f. Phys., 32, (1925), p. 518-534. http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01331692
[3] R. C. Stabler, A Possible Modification of Classical Electrodynamics, Physics Letters, 8, 3, (1964), p. 185-187. http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0031-9163(64)91989-4

Let me give you a different perspective. You should consider the asymmetry as coming more-fundamentally from the ultraviolet completion of electromagnetism into a non-Abelian Yang-Mills quantum field theory. Electric and magnetic charges are different: electric charges come from fundamental fields, but magnetic monopoles are a sort of composite particle known as a topological defect. Let me explain.
Electromagnetism by itself does not fully make sense as a quantum field theory because it is not asymptotically free. That is, if you look at how the theory behaves at shorter and shorter distances, eventually it breaks down and stops making sense.
That shouldn't be overly concerning to you because the distance scale where that happens is ridiculously tiny, and as long as we only ask questions about longer distances we can work perfectly well with quantum electromagnetism as an effective field theory.
But even better, we have a great idea what this is telling us about the quantum field theory of our universe: As we go to smaller distances, electromagnetism could unify with the other forces into a non-Abelian Yang-Mills quantum field theory. This was the beautiful realization first of $SU(5)$ grand unification. Such a non-Abelian theory can be asymptotically free, and we can look at the theory on arbitrarily small distances and it still makes sense.
Now finally to the monopoles. At small distances (or high energies) when we have $SU(5)$ there are only fundamental fields with (the generalization of) electric charges. Then as we look at larger distances we see this larger symmetry spontaneously break down to the Standard Model symmetry. It is in this spontaneous symmetry breaking phase transition that magnetic monopoles can appear as topological defects. Indeed at long distances these look roughly like a sort of discontinuity in the electromagnetic field. But at short distances you see the Higgs field that spontaneously broke the non-Abelian symmetry has a sort of 'winding' around its internal space.
This sort of thing happens in any unified theory. So I say the difference at low energies with the magnetic equations requiring a singularity to violate them is telling you something physical. It is because magnetic monopoles really need an ultraviolet completion of the electromagnetic theory, whereas electric charges do not.
